# What is the output format of PINxn on atmega328p

Tags: arduino-uno

I have written this simple code to run on my Arduino:

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 16000000UL // 16 MHz clock speed
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  DDRD = 0x00;
  PORTD = 0x80; //activate pull-up resistor on first pin on port D

  while (1)
  {
    Serial.print(PIND);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I simply set my D port as an input and read the value in a loop. The output of PIND is 253. What is this number representing? is it in decimals? where can I see a list of these? How can I see a binary repression of the PIN output (8 bits of them). I don not want to use bit shifting.

Comment: FYI, I ran your code with my MEga2560 and I all get 11111111 constantly.
Maybe you should try another PORT block or even another Arduino.

Comment: I just tried PORTB and it's all 1's `111111`, (side question, why is port B having only 6 bits?). So whats going on with PORTD here, broken board?

Answer (score 2):

`Serial.print(PIND, BIN);` will write the value in `PIND` to the serial port in Base-2 representation.

Comment: so 253 is decimal then (11111101 in base 2). isn't it supposed to be `1000 0000` since only pin 1 is turned into input? what does this number mean

Comment: That depends on what you have connected to all the pins of PORTD. If only pin 7 has something connected, and the others do not have the pull-up enabled, they are floating and could be any value.

Comment: I just enabled the pull up on all PORD by `PORTD = 0xFF;` with nothing connected to them and it's still outputting `11111101`

Answer (score 0):

From the Atmega 323p datasheet: "Writing a logic one to PINxn toggles the value of PORTxn, independent on the value of DDRxn", which is probably not what you meant to do. To read the current state of register D, you need to read PORTD, or

```
Serial.print(PORTD);
```

in your example.

Update:

> ... what is PIND used for ...

PINx is called the Port x Input Pins Address and a note under it says "Writing to the pin register provides toggle functionality for IO" and refers us to the general pin-driver circuit schematic (Section 41.2 in my copy of the datasheet). That section tells us that "Writing a logic one to PINxn toggles the value of PORTxn, independent on the value of DDRxn." That is the only reference to this register I could find.

Note that the PORTx registers are bi-directional; the same register is used for reading or setting the states of the port's bits.

> Also i'm not Writing a logic one to PINxn anywhere, i'm just reading
>   it

The datasheet doesn't mention what is read from the port, at least nowhere that I found, despite that the PINx register is described as Read/Write, so your guess is as good as mine! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ 
But to read a port's data, you need to read its PORTx register.

Update 2:

> 6 & 7map to the crystal pins and are not usable

They are usable. You can use them for I/O or for an external crystal, but not both. The "why?" is properly the domain of Atmel's engineers but I'll take a stab at it and say that many more functions could be put on the chip than there is space for physical pins on the package. Since pin count is at a premium, functions have to be doubled up on the same pins; you get to choose what you need. SPI, PWM, or I/O on DIP B2&3; Reset and I/O on C6; Timer-counter 1 input, I/O, & PWM on D5, for a few examples. Nearly every pin has several possible uses (power and grounds being the notable exceptions). For my uses, I dedicate the Crystal, Reset, and UART pins to those functions, but I could imagine systems that might need to reassign any of them.

Comment: then what is PIND used for in this case? what does `253` represent, why using PINB instead gives me the correct output of all being 1's and PORTD isn't.

Comment: Also i'm not Writing a logic one to PINxn anywhere, i'm just reading it

Comment: Quick question, why is Arduino port mapping to Atmel chip not a direct map. For example, on PORTB, `6 & 7map to the crystal pins and are not usable`, why is that? what If I wanted to use them?

Answer (score 0):

The Serial port is at pin 0 and 1.
PORTD is for pin 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7. That's the problem, you mess with the pins of the Serial port.

Note: When a crystal/resonator/clock is used, those pins are disconnected from PORTB. That means you may use PORTB and read and write 8 bits to it, the crystal will keep on running.

Comment: So basically I shouldn't use PORTD for inputs to be safe?

Comment: Quick question, why is Arduino port mapping to Atmel chip not a direct map. For example, on PORTB, 16 & 7map to the crystal pins and are not usable`, why is that? what If I wanted to use them?

Comment: After calling `Serial.begin` don't change any of those two bits in the registers. You can use the other six bits. The functionality of each pin is fixed. When using a crystal, you can no longer use those same pins for something else, since they are connected to the crystal. I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: question is, atmega328p has 8 bits in port B. but Arduino has 6 (2 port are reserved for something else), why is that?

Comment: Portb.6 and Portb.7 are pins for the crystal. When no crystal is used, they can be normal digital pins. The atmega chip can not assign a function to an other pin. The serial port, the crystal, the i2c bus, the analog inputs, everything is fixed to certain pins. A single pin can however act as a number of different things.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte valueB = PINB; // reads the value of portB, D14-D19, into the variable valueB
```

If you then

```
Serial.print (valueB,BIN);
```

you will see the value of D19 to D14 in binary, or 0s & 1s. I don't think leading zero's are shown, so that can be a little confusing.

```
Serial.print (valueB);
```

will show the same value in decimal.
253 = 0b11111101   0b indicates base 2 (binary) format.  0x is used fof hexidecimal format (0x00 to 0xFF for 0 to 255).

If you are using the IDE and have not changed the fuses from the Uno/Nano board type, the IDE is expecting a crystal or resonator on PB7 & PB6, so reading them will return a nonsense result, so you might as well mask them off before printing.

```
valueB = valueB & 0b00111111;
```

If the other pins do not have their internal pullup resistors turned on, or external pullup or pulldown resistors are not used, the pins are 'floating' and their low input current means that any external charge can easily change their reading - so valueB = PINB; will have erratic results.

If a port has been set to outputs, then all pins can be written to at once:

```
PORTB = 0b0011111111;  // set D19 to D14 high for example
```